# Proper way of installing per-user files during a per-machine installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a per-machine WiX installer (InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated") and I need to create a folder and copy a few files to the Documents folder of each user running the application.  At the moment I install the files to a personal folder of the current user, but that's wrong and I get the ICE91 verification warning:

```
ICE91: The file 'SomeFile' will be installed to the per user directory 'SomeDir'
that doesn't vary based on ALLUSERS value. This file won't be copied to each
user's profile even if a per machine installation is desired.
```

I want the files to be automatically copied to the Documents folder of each user.  Could someone post the step-by-step instructions how to do that?

UPDATE: I will be on holiday until September, during that time I will not be able to respond to any comments.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Installer will do this - it's what advertised shortcuts will do. If you install a file to a user specific folder location and a different user logs on, then that file will be missing for that user and repair mechanism of the advertised shortcut repair will install it from the original MSI file. In your case the PersonalFolder property is the user's Documents folder.

To arrange this, the file must be the keypath of a component, and that component must be in a feature with an advertised shortcut. When the shortcut is used the component and containing feature are checked for "self healing" and the missing file installed. This works for users that don't yet exist. Older Office installers once did this to install user-specific items such as templates.

The MSI must obviously be available for this to work, and there is no mechanism to remove the files at uninstall time.

An alternative (or if there are no advertised shortcuts) is to add code to the app that calls MsiProvideComponment (or equivalent p/invoke) passing the ProductCode, feature name, Component id (of that documents file) and use INSTALLMODE_DEFAULT, which will install the file if it's missing as documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370356(v=vs.85).aspx

and it will be missing and therefore will be installed for a user who has not run the app before.

Comment: TIL that this is even possible

Comment: Note that it requires the original .msi (and .cabs, if external) to be available to every user.

Comment: I changed the feature to be advertised, but it didn't help.  All files I install have their keypath property set to true, they belong to a component group which is added to a feature.  What's missing?

Comment: It's not the feature that's advertised, it's the shortcut. The first test to do is the remove the file from your current installed product, then use the shortcut and see if it re-installs the file. If that works for you then it will work for other users for whom the file is missing.

Comment: Hmmm.... The shortcut to the main executable is advertised, but no repair happens when I delete the file and try to launch the application using the shortcut.

Comment: You'll need to post a complete WiX source example that shows the failure to repair, maybe as another post. There are too many reasons why it might not work to go through here - the straightforward way is post a failing WiX example.

Comment: Today I'm going on holiday, I will publish a sample WiX installer when I'm back in September.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this this way? What if there are 10000 (just for example) users on the machine? You want to copy the files to all 10000 documents folders taking up potentially GBs of space (depending on the size if the files copied)? If these are configuration options needed by your app, the app itself should create default files in the user's documents location on the first run if they are not present otherwise load the settings from these files. You should not put the default files there for every single user on the machine at install time.

This approach also fails for new users added after you install. How will they get the files in their documents folder? Do they have to reinstall the product?

Comment: I inherited a project from another developer who left and I have no choice but to keep the original design, it would be a breaking change the users wouldn't like to move the files somewhere else.  I asked the same question as you - how are new users going to get the files in their documents folder?  The files are small, so it's not going to be GB of data and engineers (users of my software) normally don't create 1000 users on their machines at work.

Comment: That was just an exaggerated example to show why I think it's a bad practice to do it that way. The advertise method appears to be what you would want but getting it working seems potentially complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a per machine install of per user installers with shortcuts that interested users could launch. For example, templates.msi, examples.msi.